# Is it possible to replace a transformation matrix (square matrix) by a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$ which acts on an $n\times1$ vector $x$ to give a particular vector $y$ as a result. Is it possible to produce a unitary matrix which gives the same result $y$ when acting upon $x$?

Comment: Well, for $x, y\in\mathbb{C}^n$, there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $Ux=y$ if and only if $\|x\|=\|y\|$, where $\|z\|=\sqrt{|z_1|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, this is not always possible, as a unitary matrix leaves the norm of a vector invariant, whereas your original matrix might change the norm.